# VueJs TestUtil: In jest unit testing, html is not reactive when data is modified in mounted hook

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

While jest unit testing for a component, if the component has mounted hook to update the data, after that the html is no longer reactive. It's stuck with the data before the modification by mounted hook.
The **testutil** version is: **1.0.0-beta.29**

component: count.ts

```typescript
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  template: `
  <div>
    count:{{ count }}
    <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export default class Count extends Vue {
  count = 0;
  mounted() {
    // comment following line, everything works fine.
    this.count = 10;
  }

  increment() {
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

testing spec: count.spec.ts

```typescript
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Counter from './counter';

it('button click should increment the count', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Counter);
  const button = wrapper.find('button');
  button.trigger('click');
  console.log(`wrapper.vm.count=${wrapper.vm.count}`);
  console.log(`html=${wrapper.html()}`);
});
```

If I comment out the line in `mounted()`, everything works fine.   Otherwise, the output will be

```
wrapper.vm.count=11
html=<div>
  count:0
  <button>Increment</button></div>
```

The html is supposed to print `count:11` instead of `count:0`.

Comment: I think you need to define count in the data section instead of a local variable.

Comment: In typescript class based component, we can just define data as normal class variable. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components